# Switch to default case in switch-case

Tags: java, switch-statement, default

Is it possible to go to the default case while I'm in case 1/2/etc.?

```
switch(num) {
    case 1:
        if(foo) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //go to default
        }

        ...
        ...
        ...

    default:
        //do something
}
```

Comment: No, Java doesn't support the ability to `goto` a switch case.

Comment: That would be awful. Just create a method doDefault(), and call it from the default case and from the else branch of case 1.

Comment: Awful? C# has this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even if you change `num` value when you are in `switch` the value for comparision is the value of variable **before** start of switch so if you've entered one of `case` branches you cannot enter again into `default`.

However you can do something like

```
boolean doDefault = false;
switch(num) {
    case 1:
        if(foo) {
            ...
        }
        else {
            doDefault = true;
        }
        break;
}

if(doDefault) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write the logic that is supposed to happen in the `default` block in a function and call it when necessary:

```
void defAction(){
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

int main() {

    int num = 1, foo = 0;

    switch(num) {
        case 1:
            if(foo) {
                printf("Goodbye, World!\n");
            } else {
                defAction();
            }
            break;
        default:
            defAction();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Remember, that if a case does not use `break;`, all cases below it (including `default`) are also called. This way, if you only break out of the switch `if(foo)`, it will proceed to the `default`.
This is only really useful, if you want to jump to `default` from no more than one `case`, in which case you put that `case` last, right before `default`.

**use with caution / see comments below**

```
switch(num) {
    case 2:
        // do sth
        break;
    case 3:
        // do sth
        break;
    case 4:
        // do sth
        break;
    case 1:
        if(foo) {
            printf("Goodbye, World!\n");
            break;
        }
        // ELSE don't break, use default
    default:
        defAction();
}
```

Comment: The latter one is ugly, bound to be misread by most future programmers touching the code. It would at the very least require a comment in capital letters warning the reader.

Comment: @OleV.V. you're right! I personally have no problem with such solutions, but others might. I edited my answer accordingly…

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to make a method

```
switch(num) {
    case 1:
        if(foo) {
            //do something
        } else {
            foo();
        }
    default:
        foo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not possible,doesn't make sense in real time application or in any use case,but if you want to go in default than you can do this by any of the following way-

1. Remove all break than you will meat default at end.
2. Call goDefault() method with value not matches with any `case`.

Comment: It does make sense. C# has this.

Comment: what ever you want to achieve this,can easily achieve by calling a method.for example we have 100 case in 50 of them we want to perform some common task,create a method and call in them.Advantage default will execute only after case executes,and this can be call any where. That's why java not support it.

Comment: It has a use that cannot be achieved with a `goDefault` method: e.g. accessing local scoped variables. Of course you can implement anything in Java, but it's wrong to say that this pattern "doesn't make sense in any use case".

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, but you can call the same method or leave out the breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them before default and don't brake at the end of case, then it will execute all statements before break, no matter what is the case

Answer (score 0):

You achieve this in a way below.

Suppose you need to go to the default case after case 1,2,8 only then you can write below code.

```
 switch(Choice){
    case 1 : //do something
    case 2 : //do something
    case 8 : //do something
    default: //to do default operation   
    break;
    case 3 : 
    case 4 : 
  }
```

Comment: but if he/she needed to go from case 1 the way you propose, case 2 and case 8 would also be executed. Which is probably not at all what he/she wants.

Comment: Yes, But this is useful if the case 2 and 8 blocks are empty.